# Get echoed value from script on C

Tags: c

I'm trying to create/execute a script on C, this script should return a string which my program must read to compare it with a constant value.

So far I've been able to create and execute the script within my C program, but not sure how to get the echoed string, here is an example of my code:

```
const char *fileName = "./tmp_script";

int main()
{
  FILE *log_f;
  unsigned char *valueRead; // this variable should have the echoed string

  log_f = fopen (fileName, "a");
  if (log_f == NULL) { return -1; }
  
  fputs ("#!/bin/bash\n\n\n",log_f);
  fputs ("echo something\n",log_f); // This is the value I need
  chmod (fileName, 0777);
  fclose (log_f);
  system(fileName); //the program is executed succesfully
  
  /* Here the echoed string should be read and stored in valueRead
   * in order to compare it with another variable
   */

  remove (fileName);
  return 0;
}
```

Also, is it possible to read that value only in my program and not get it printed on the terminal?
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You need to create a *pipe* where the scripts standard output is written to and from which you can read the output. A simple way to handle is [the `popen` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

Comment: A little more specific, you need a pipe to get the string from `stdout`. And no, it's not possible to have your script output NOT appear in the terminal ... unless you send stdout to a file. In which case you might as well just read the file and not bother with pipes.

Comment: @Kevin If standard output of the script is connected to a pipe, then it won't be connected to a terminal, and no output will be written in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder !https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude !